# List comparison with comprehension giving inadequate result in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Consider following lists with example values

(here's obviously device name, serial number and other values that don't really matter)

I didn't mention that len means the actual list length. So I have 2019 elements and 2100 elements in another.

```
devices_list_foo = ['1', 'HP monitor 500', '1', 'L9K12AZU', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> len(devices_list_foo)
2019


devices_list_bar = ['london-foobar-street', 'hpmon500', 'L9K12AZU', 'some value']
>>> len(devices_list_bar)
2100
```

I had to find matches between the two lists and write them to a different list. I did it with the following line:

```
common_elements = set(i[3] for i in devices_list_foo).intersection(i[2] for i in devices_list_bar)
```

This gave me `588` common serials between lists. And then I had to make a list of what's left of these `588` - the list of machines. So `2019 - 588 = 1431` and `2100 - 588 = 1512`. So I need these `1431` and `1512` machines in lists.

Here's what I tried:
Since `common_elements` is of type `set`, then I was able to use list comprehension:

```
devices_missing_list_foo = [x for x in devices_list_foo if x[3] not in common_elements]
>>> len(devices_missing_list_foo)
1347

devices_missing_list_bar = [x for x in devices_list_bar if x[2] not in common_elements]
>>> len(devices_missing_list_bar)
1512
```

So this `1512` seems to be correct, but why do I see this `1347` instead of `1431`. How could I investigate this?

Comment: Maybe you have several occurences of a same element in your list. Check if len(set(i[3] for i in devices_list_foo)) == len(devices_list_foo).

Comment: Maybe i haven't understood completely what you are asking for but if you want to assign the common elements between two lists to another list you can always use `c_list = list(set(a_list) & set(b_list))` .

Comment: If "L9K12AZU" occurs multiple times in `devices_list_foo` it will only be counted once but will remove several items.

Comment: Why isn't the len of the first length 6?

Comment: To investigate further, try using `itertools.Counter` instead of `set`.

Comment: As I replied below, there are indeed duplicates in `devices_missing_list_foo`. How would `Counter` help me? Since `common_values` is calculated correctly, I don't really see the need for it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm am not entirely sure I understand your question. But one pitfall I think is that there seems to be duplicated values in the lists so that the length is less of the `set` that the original `list`. Ex:

```
>>> test_list = [1,2,3,1]
>>> len(test_list)
4
>>> test_set = set(test_list)
>>> len(test_set)
3
```

---

**Edit**

So we know:

- You have duplicates in your original lists
- `common_elements` is a set so there is no duplicates there

But since we do not know how many times a specific value from `common_elements` exists in the original lists (could be ones, twice or even more) your sums does not add up. Yet another example:

```
>>> a=[1,1,1,2,3]
>>> b=[3,3,3,4,5]
>>> set(a)
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> set(b)
set([3, 4, 5])
>>> common_elements=set(a).intersection(b)
>>> common_elements
set([3])
>>> a_missing=[x for x in a if x not in common]
>>> b_missing=[x for x in b if x not in common]
>>> a_missing
[1, 1, 1, 2]
>>> b_missing
[4, 5]
```

**NOTE** `len(b_missing)+len(common_elements) <> len(b)`

Comment: You're right, `devices_list_foo` has duplicate serialnumbers on index `3`. Since these values come from Excel, then by using Excel, I found that I've got `243` duplicates. Then again, the difference between values in my original post - `1347` and `1431` is not `243`.